# How to plot graph of this function

Tags: python, matplotlib

Where could the problem be? I am trying to build a Huber function, but the result is very strange and not like the Huber function.

My [data](https://www.kaggle.com/account/login?returnUrl=%2Fnehalbirla%2Fvehicle-dataset-from-cardekho%2Fversion%2F1)

```
def f(y,fx):
    delta = 1
    if m.fabs(y-fx)<=delta:
        return 1/2*(y-fx)**2
    else:
        return delta*m.fabs(y-fx)-1/2*delta**2

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
X = data.iloc[:,2] 
y = data.iloc[:,3] 
func = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(X, y, 1, full=True)[0])

x = np.arange(0., 3.01, 0.01)
y_new = []

for i in range(len(X)):
   y_new.append(f(y[i],func(X[i])))

print(y_new)

plt.plot(x,y_new,c='red', ls='', ms=5, marker='.')
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_ylim([-1, 2])
plt.show()
```

[image]
[image: graph]

Comment: It's hard to know what the issue is here without seeing your plots and what you expected. Did you encounter an error? Did your poly1d fit function produce the correct result? What data did you load from the csv?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @aorr updated post

Comment: `data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')` <--- what are we supposed to do about this?

Comment: @PaulH For example download and test. Link to this dataset is in this post

Comment: the plot on the left, 'expected', is in residual space, i.e., the x axis is y - f(x) _not_ x. The one on the right called 'have' appears to be in natural x,y space. How do you know your huber loss function did not work? Did your polyfit work to fit your data? If not, we'd expect weird results when you use it in your loop (also, consider numpy arrays for this. Look into "array broadcasting"). Can you show us what you've done to explore and debug this?